# Use Old GCC Version

Tags: gcc, downgrade

I've been trying to get an old version of GCC for my Ubuntu but I can't find any working way to achieve that.
I'd like to use the version 4.1.2 of GCC, and I currently got the 4.7.2.

How may I install GCC 4.1.2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not have SVN install it with

```
sudo apt-get install svn
```

Then run the following command and it will download the source for gcc 4.1.2 into a subdirectory of the current working directory.

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags/gcc_4_1_2_release gcc
```

Then follow the [official gcc build guide](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/)